# how to Get data from different folder file and that html file name using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    var fileName = ["login", "logout"];
    
    fileName.forEach(function(Value) {
    
      $.get('views/'+Value+'.html', function(result) {
        var title = $(result).find('title').innerHTML;// this is title value
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.Obj = {
    Allcontent: []
};
var ContentName = [];

    $scope.fileName = ["login", "info"];// html file names
    var input = document.getElementById("Myinput");// search box id
    var value = input.value.toUpperCase();
        angular.forEach($scope.fileName, function(Value) {
            $.get('file/'+Value+'.html', function(result) {
                var input, filter, title, i;
                var path = $(result).find('meta').content;
                input = $(result).find('h1').innerHTML.toUpperCase();
                title = $(result).find('title').innerHTML.toUpperCase();
                
                $scope.Obj['Allcontent'].push({"Value":title, "Path":path});
                $scope.Obj['Allcontent'].push({"Value":input, "Path":path});
                
                ContentName.push(title);
                ContentName.push(input);
                ContentName= [ ...new Set(ContentName) ];// for remove duplicate values
                $scope.getContentName= ContentName.filter(el => el.includes(value));
            });
        });
```